# Robotics Stack Exchange and Robotics Meta Stack Exchange difference

Tags: ros

I am here because of the ROS Answers migration, but I'm new to Stack Exchange and I realized there is Robotics Stack Exchange and Robotics Meta Stack Exchange, can someone explain the difference between the two? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question that's suited for the Robotics Meta site, because this is a question about the site itself and not a question about a Robotics topic.

If you had a question about why another question was closed, or how to add a tag to the site, or what privileges you get at various reputation levels, or have any other public Q&A about the site itself, those all go on the meta portion.

Everything about robots, ROS, etc. all go on the "regular" Robotics Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, now its clear for me where to ask my questions depending on the topic.